# Language in which to write a mouse gesture application for linux?

Tags: linux, gesture-recognition

I'm a bit of a mouse gesture fanatic (I love them!). On Windows, I use the awesome application Strokeit (simply perfect) for my mouse gesture needs. But on Linux there exists no sweet mouse gesture app. So I want to code my own (at least give it a shot).

So: which language should I choose to write a mouse gesture app for linux ? I know PHP, C# and a bit of C.

Comment: Have you tried Gestikk or EasyStroke?

Answer (score 1):

You don't

```
sudo apt-get build-dep wayv
apt-get source wayv --compile
```

And you'll have the source code done. It's in ANSI C, for the record:

```
Totals grouped by language (dominant language first):
ansic:         1658 (100.00%)
```

I don't know how good it is, but certainly good enough to be improved by you!

### Update

Also, according to [this StrokeIt thread](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/forum/read.php?3,11394), there is something new going on at http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~deters/xgestures